# How to implement Azure multi tenant app access in angular 2

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, angular2-services, angular2-directives, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm new to angular 2 . I am working on Multi Tenant application in angular 2.
I have done Multi Tenant application in ASP.netMVC.But in angular2 i'm not getting any idea.

**I have done single tenant authentication in Angular 2 by [following this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/26/using-adal-with-angular2/)**

any anser appriciated.

**Thanks in Advance....!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly ,you can make your registration multi-tenant by finding the "Multi-Tenanted" switch on the properties page of your application registration in the Azure portal and setting it to "Yes".

Then please update your code to send requests to /common .With a multi-tenant application, the application doesn’t know up front what tenant the user is from, so you can’t send requests to a tenant’s endpoint. Instead, requests are sent to an endpoint that multiplexes across all Azure AD tenants:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
```

In your code , try to replace `tenant` value to `common` . Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview) for more details about how to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern .

Comment: Thanks. I followed the example you listed in your answer, and I can login to my Angular app with accounts from other tenants now. The user's name and email show in the app. So I know they are logged in and authenticated. However, when I login with one of these other tenant account, I now get an error on all API calls: "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID...". I am using @azure/msal-angular and its MsalInterceptor. Do I need to change something else there or in my API applications? It is an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API. Any ideas?

Comment: @BobbyOrtiz , [Understand user and admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent) , you need the permission in that tenant to register the application in that tenant

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Once admin consent was given in the second tenant, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to access multi tenant app in Angular 2.
by tenant value  as `common`

Thanks Nan

```
    public AdalConfig(): any {
    return {
        tenant: 'common',
        clientId: 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx',
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
        postLogoutRediFFFFrectUri: window.location.origin + '/'
    };

}
```

Comment: Please mark my reply as answer if it helps , it will help others who meet same problem .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.                                   I'm getting this Nan while mark your reply......!

Comment: To  mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green  , see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) .